Fast retrieval of all subsets of an arbitrary set from a list of sets in R
Is there a way of doing fast retrieval of all strict subsets of a set over a list (e.g. subsets binary encoded as a matrix where each row represents a subset) in R? I think a tree would suffice, but I wonder

Is there a package that does this sort of things and
If not, how to code a tree in R? I've done this in C++ but barely have tried any more advanced data structures in R.

An example of the data is a list with two elements: [{a,b}, {a,b,c}]. This can be written in R as:
matrix(c(1,1,0,1,1,1),nrow = 2,byrow = TRUE)

We want a function subset(A) as:
Subsets of c(1,1,1) should give matrix(c(1,1,0), nrow=1) because there's only the first set in the list that's a strict subset of it.
Subsets of c(1,1,0) should give NULL because there's no sets in the list that's a strict subset of it.
A similar question is Fast Data structure for finding strict subsets (from a given list) but in this question we're interested in programming this in R.

do you mean {a,b} is the parent node of {a,b,c}?

{a,b,c} is the children of {a,b,c} because it's a subset of it

The list is [{a,b}, {a,b,c}]

I already coded this in r. It's represented as a binary matrix matrix(c(1,1,0,1,1,1),nrow = 2). The first row is {a,b} and the second row is {a,b,c}.

Here f(x,y) is TRUE if vector x, a row of the matrix, is a subset of vector y, another row. Also res[i,j] is TRUE if row number j is a subset of row number i f <- function(x,y) all(x >= y);Rows <- asplit(M, 1);res <- outer(Rows, Rows, Vectorize(f));res  If that is not fast enough use Rcpp package to interface R to your C++ code.

There is an easy way you can do this if your sets are columns instead of rows, by using logical ANDs and colSums(). Test data: mat <- matrix(c(T,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,T,T),nrow=3) then you can do colSums(mat[,3] & !mat) - R does the logical AND column-wise, so this command gives you a per-column total of "rows that are T in mat[,3] but not in the current column". When that sum is 0, mat[,3] is a subset of the current column.

@TiredSquirrel I'm not looking for a per column total. I'm just wanting to return the entire list of subsets. In this case it should return NULL (empty set).

The sum is just a means to an end. You can use it to detect which columns are subsets (sum=0) or are not (sum!=0) and then once you know which columns are subsets the function can return appropriate values.

Maybe you can try tcrossprod + rowSums like below to find all subsets, and then apply colMeans to filter "strictly subsets", e.g.,
f <- function(mat, v) {
  mat[tcrossprod(v, mat) == rowSums(mat) & colMeans(t(mat) == v) < 1, ,drop = FALSE]
}

where

tcrossprod(v, mat) == rowSums(mat) checks if number of 1s in each row of mat is less than or equal to number of 1s in v
colMeans(t(mat) == v) < 1 excludes v from mat rows, i.e., strict subset

Example
Given data mat like
> set.seed(1)

> (mat <- unique(matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 20)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    1    0    1
 [2,]    1    0    1    1    1
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    1    1    0
 [5,]    1    0    1    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    1    1    1
 [7,]    0    1    1    1    0
 [8,]    1    0    0    1    0
 [9,]    1    1    0    1    1
[10,]    0    1    0    1    0
[11,]    0    1    1    0    1
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0
[13,]    1    1    1    1    0
[14,]    1    0    1    0    1
[15,]    1    1    1    0    1

we can obtain
> f(mat, c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    1    1
[5,]    0    1    1    1    0
[6,]    0    1    0    1    0
[7,]    0    1    1    0    1
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0

> f(mat, c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0

> f(mat, c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0


Could you write some explanations of what each of the component does? Would be interested in knowing how much memory is needed. I tried it and it seems really fast at least on a small problem.

@monotonic see my added comments
